# Angular Servicios

Tags: angular

Como puedo declarar parámetros en un servicio de Angular, si dichos parámetros son opcionales en el WebService.
Mi WebService tiene 4 parámetros opcionales, le estoy enviando hasta el momento dos, pero me he encontrado los siguientes inconvenientes:

**1-** **return this.http.get(call,{headers:headers,params:{'storeId':storeId,'promoId':promoId}})**; (
Me retorna la información filtrando por los dos parámetros.

**2-** **return this.http.get(call,{headers:headers,params:{'storeId':storeId}});** (me envía mensaje de error, ya que solo hay un parámetro declarado al momento del llamado).

Si son opcionales, porque se comporta de ésta manera, si alguien puede indicarme por favor, la manera de enviar éstos parámetros, hay una mejor manera de validar cuando los parámetros del webservice son opcionales.
Gracias de antemano a los que pueden ayudarme,

Comment: Te refieres que son opcionales en el código de Angular o en el back-end?

Answer (score 1):

Hola si para poder enviar los parametros como lo pides utiliza la clase `HttpParams` te facilitaria un poco armar la estructura de los parametros para el *request*.

Ejemplo

```js
metodoTest(request){
    let httpParams: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
    if(request.storeId != null){
        httpParams = httpParams.append('storeId', request.storeId.toString());
    }
    if(request.promoId != null){
        httpParams = httpParams.append('promoId', request.promoId.toString());
    }
    ...
    return this.http.get(endpoint, httpParams);
}
```

En tal caso de que manejes el envio de parametros al servicio de manera diferente puede ser.

```js
metodoTest(storeId, promoId, ...){
    let httpParams: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
    if(storeId != null){
        httpParams = httpParams.append('storeId', storeId.toString());
    }
    if(promoId != null){
        httpParams = httpParams.append('promoId', promoId.toString());
    }
    ...
    return this.http.get(endpoint, httpParams);
}
```

siguiendo la estructura de la [documentacion](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams) de angular `append(param: string, value: string)`

y asi continuas con los demas parametros si tienes.